# Python pip install error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm having constant problems with installing packages for python.

Previously, I just fixed the missing Visual C++ 14.0 error, now this.

[image]

Comment: Did you install pip with anacondas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

pip install mysql-python is not supported

Comment: Thanks a lot, does it mean I can use 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql' now?

Comment: yes, you can use it in database now in django settings