# Error installing mysqlclient or/and mysql-python in Windows 10

Tags: python, mysql, pip

I installed Django correctly in a folder in Windows 10 Home and I need to connect this app with Mysql. 
When I execute pip install  mysqlclient or/and mysql-python I have this error.

```
_mysql.c
_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\xampp\htdocs\worldfeeding\env\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import 
setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ceju8r0r\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-r4bwaq6w\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\xampp\htdocs\worldfeeding\env\include\site\python3.7\mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ceju8r0r\mysqlclient\
```

Searching, I tried the solutions from the answers in:

[error: command 'C:\\ Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494411/error-command-c-visual-studio-2017-community-vc-tools-msvc-14-14-2642)

[Python pip install error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44311318/python-pip-install-error-command-c-program-files-x86-microsoft-visual-stu?rq=1)

But not working.

So, I installed paquets from Visual Studio Community 2017, following the instructions from the answer in those links and not working.

I installed mysql-web-community, with mysql server.

I download VS and Twisted-18.4.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl but not working.

I tryed with npm install --global --production windows-build-tools and nothing.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Did you actually install the mysql server? It's not clear.

Comment: Sorry, I just edit the question.

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25445938/1138946

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failing to install mysqlclient in python virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315405/failing-to-install-mysqlclient-in-python-virtualenv)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Cannot+open+include+file%3A+%27mysql.h%27%3A+No+such+file+or+directory